# IOBluetooth block by sandbox access

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, bluetooth

I'm trying to use IOBluetooth with Xcode 12.5.1 on MacOS 11.4 to get a list of bluetooth devices connected to my computer. However I'm getting this error.

> [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in
> CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600000af6b80> (Domain: com.apple.Bluetooth, User:
> kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need
> Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's
> container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox
> access

After doing some google searching and enabling every permission in App Sandboxing and adding Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description and Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description to info.plist I get the same result. I can't seem to find out what's causing the problem.

Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa
import IOBluetooth

class ViewController: NSViewController {

let ioBluetoothDevice = IOBluetoothDevice()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(IOBluetoothDevice.pairedDevices() ?? "No Paired Devices") // <- returns empty array even though I have a keyboard and mouse connected
        
    }

}
```

Comment: See the Info.plist.

Comment: @El Tomato what Key/Value do I need to add though? I tried adding Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description and Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description and got the same result

Comment: There are only three places to look at: Capabilities, Info.plist, Development profile.  Besides, take a very good look at the error message you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had enabled Bluetooth for the App Sandbox on the wrong target. *(Thanks @El Tomato)*